# I need a regex which will return the space delimited contents of a string

Tags: regex, vba

I need a regex, suitable for VBA, which will retrieve groups of data from string.

I think I have some of the required regex however there may be a better more efficient way?

The string is:

```
("xs:/49.dwp" 149 (nil "sdfsfda" "16-12-10") ("V" "5" "R" "1" ",A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J") (nil "gt:\\lib\\iec2;gt://Libs/iec3/;gt://Libs/hyd/;gt://Libs/pid/;") ("xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht" "xs:\\a-04.sht") ((1 "01A" "" "xs:\\a-01.sht" "dgddgdfgd" "" "" "" "") (2 "" "" "xs:\\a-01A.sht""ergfdgdfgdtger44" "" "" "" "") (3 "" "" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "34vbb" "" "" "" "")) ("xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht""xs:\\a-04.sht" "xs:\\a-09.sht" "xs:\\a-10.sht" "xs:\\a-11.sht" "xs:\\a-12.sht") nil ("xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht""xs:\\a-04.sht" "xs:\\a-09.sht" "xs:\\a-10.sht" "xs:\\a-11.sht" "xs:\\a-12.sht") (("" "xs:\\a-01.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-01A.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-02.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-03.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-11.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-12.sht")))
```

In this string there are 11 individual groups I need to get.  Each group is delimited by a space.

Some groups only consist of text surrounded by quotes, some are numbers and some are a series of texts surrounded by quotes.  All of the 11 groups are also surrounded by a pair of brackets.

I'll describe the 11 groups and what I have so far:

Group 1 - `"xs:/49.dwp"`.  I have `^\("(.+)" \d+` which returns `xs:/49.dwp`

Group 2 - `149`. I have `" (\d{3}) \(` which returns `149`

So far so good!!

Group 3 - `(nil "sdfsfda" "16-12-10")`

Group 4 - `("V" "5" "R" "1" ",A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J")`

Group 5 - `(nil "gt:\\lib\\iec2;gt://Libs/iec3/;gt://Libs/hyd/;gt://Libs/pid/;")`

Group 6 - `("xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht" "xs:\\a-04.sht")`

Group 7 - `((1 "01A" "" "xs:\\a-01.sht" "dgddgdfgd" "" "" "" "") (2 "" "" "xs:\\a-01A.sht""ergfdgdfgdtger44" "" "" "" "") (3 "" "" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "34vbb" "" "" "" ""))`

Group 8 - `("xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht""xs:\\a-04.sht" "xs:\\a-09.sht" "xs:\\a-10.sht" "xs:\\a-11.sht" "xs:\\a-12.sht")`

Group 9 - `nil`

Group 10 - `("xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht""xs:\\a-04.sht" "xs:\\a-09.sht" "xs:\\a-10.sht" "xs:\\a-11.sht" "xs:\\a-12.sht")`

Group 11 - `(("" "xs:\\a-01.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-01A.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-02.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-03.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-11.sht") ("" "xs:\\a-12.sht"))`

Between groups 3 and 11, I was trying to get a pattern which matched everything in between an opening bracket and a closing bracket in order to get all of the groups but there are a couple of issues here.

1) There are groups of groups surrounded by brackets, such as in groups 7 and 11.

2) Group 9 in the middle of these bracketed groups which is not surrounded by brackets.

I need a regex to capture 11 groups.  I don't need the outer surrounding group brackets but I obviously need the brackets of the inner groups.

Comment: Is the only information that you want to grab out of those groups the information that looks like `xs:\\a-01.sht` ?

Comment: `/(\([^()]*\))/g` could help. Try messing around with it at https://regex101.com/r/JN0nXe/2

Answer (score 0):

> **DISCLAIMER:** I'm risking starting a flame war here, because I'm not a
>   big fan of regular expressions. Now you know my bias, but I still
>   think I have a point pertaining to this particular question. If you
>   want to get deeper into a regexp discussion, you can read [this
>   article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) and [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113243/339464) for some good points.

Trying to come up with a regular expression for your input string will be problematic for a couple reasons:

1. Your definition of delimiters for the groups is inconsistent and would be difficult to implement. As an example, your first group starts with a paren `"("` but ends with a space `" "`. The second group starts and ends with spaces. Your third group starts and ends with parens BUT CONTAINS spaces. You might eventually write a successful regexp, but it would give me a headache to understand it.
2. Your example input is only that - an example. Other input lines will have their own "exceptions" to whatever rules you define in your regexp statement. This, in turn, will cause you to modify your regexp and make it even more obtuse (and possibly break your previous rules).

My suggestion is to parse the input using a few, well-defined rules that are both easy to enforce on your input and to implement in your logic. To support my suggestion, I slightly modified some token parsing code I have in my personal library. The idea of this function is to repeatedly parse a single string and pull out all of the "token" substrings enclosed by a defined start and stop character.

```
Private Function GetNextToken(ByRef startAt As Long, _
                              ByVal str As String, _
                              Optional ByVal startCharacter As String = "(", _
                              Optional ByVal stopCharacter As String = ")") As String
    Dim thisToken As String
    Dim thisChar As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = startAt To Len(str)
        thisChar = Mid$(str, i, 1)
        Select Case thisChar
            Case startCharacter, stopCharacter
                Exit For
            Case Else
                thisToken = thisToken & thisChar
        End Select
    Next i
    startAt = i + 1
    GetNextToken = Trim$(thisToken)
End Function
```

Notice that the parameter `startAt` is passed `ByRef`. This means that its value will be modified by the function and passed back to the caller. The function will effectively "walk" the starting point for parsing down the string. So it scans the input string until it hits either a start or stop character, (possibly) building up a string along the way. Empty strings are `Trim`med to a null string.

To use the function, I put your sample input in cell A1 and used the following test program:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ParseMe()
    Dim source As String
    source = Range("A1").Value

    Dim token As String
    Dim tokens As Collection
    Set tokens = New Collection

    Dim startAt As Long
    'source = "(abcd(efg(hijklm)))"
    startAt = 1
    Do While startAt < Len(source)
        token = GetNextToken(startAt, source)
        'Debug.Print "token is '" & token & "', next start at " & startAt
        If Not token = vbNullString Then
            tokens.Add token
        End If
    Loop

    Dim thisToken As Variant
    Debug.Print "there are " & tokens.Count & " tokens:"
    For Each thisToken In tokens
        Debug.Print "   " & thisToken
    Next thisToken
End Sub
```

This gives the output (using your sample input):

```
there are 17 tokens:
   "xs:/49.dwp" 149
   nil "sdfsfda" "16-12-10"
   "V" "5" "R" "1" ",A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J"
   nil "gt:\\lib\\iec2;gt://Libs/iec3/;gt://Libs/hyd/;gt://Libs/pid/;"
   "xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht" "xs:\\a-04.sht"
   1 "01A" "" "xs:\\a-01.sht" "dgddgdfgd" "" "" "" ""
   2 "" "" "xs:\\a-01A.sht""ergfdgdfgdtger44" "" "" "" ""
   3 "" "" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "34vbb" "" "" "" ""
   "xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht""xs:\\a-04.sht" "xs:\\a-09.sht" "xs:\\a-10.sht" "xs:\\a-11.sht" "xs:\\a-12.sht"
   nil
   "xs:\\a-01.sht" "xs:\\a-01A.sht" "xs:\\a-02.sht" "xs:\\a-03.sht""xs:\\a-04.sht" "xs:\\a-09.sht" "xs:\\a-10.sht" "xs:\\a-11.sht" "xs:\\a-12.sht"
   "" "xs:\\a-01.sht"
   "" "xs:\\a-01A.sht"
   "" "xs:\\a-02.sht"
   "" "xs:\\a-03.sht"
   "" "xs:\\a-11.sht"
   "" "xs:\\a-12.sht"
```

After this, it's up to you and your business logic to decide whether an individual token (the first one: `"xs:/49.dwp" 149`) should be broken up using the space delimiter. If so, you can just use the `Split` function:

```
Split(token, " ")
```